# Web component dragging functionality to slideer

Tags: javascript, web-component

I'm working with this Web component from a Shopify theme and I need to add drag and drop functionality to it. Swiping on mobile and desktop currently work as well as the buttons, but I can't figure out how to get the dragging to work.

The console logs work show the updated position but the slider never moves

```
class SliderComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.slider = this.querySelector('[id^="Slider-"]');
    this.sliderItems = this.querySelectorAll('[id^="Slide-"]');
    this.enableSliderLooping = false;
    this.currentPageElement = this.querySelector('.slider-counter--current');
    this.pageTotalElement = this.querySelector('.slider-counter--total');
    this.prevButton = this.querySelector('button[name="previous"]');
    this.nextButton = this.querySelector('button[name="next"]');

    if (!this.slider || !this.nextButton) return;

    this.initPages();
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => this.initPages());
    resizeObserver.observe(this.slider);

    this.slider.addEventListener('scroll', this.update.bind(this));
    this.prevButton.addEventListener('click', this.onButtonClick.bind(this));
    this.nextButton.addEventListener('click', this.onButtonClick.bind(this));

    this.onDrag = this.onDrag.bind(this);
    this.stopDragging = this.stopDragging.bind(this);

    this.slider.addEventListener('mousedown', this.startDragging.bind(this));

  }

  initPages() {
    this.sliderItemsToShow = Array.from(this.sliderItems).filter((element) => element.clientWidth > 0);
    if (this.sliderItemsToShow.length < 2) return;
    this.sliderItemOffset = this.sliderItemsToShow[1].offsetLeft - this.sliderItemsToShow[0].offsetLeft;
    this.slidesPerPage = Math.floor(
      (this.slider.clientWidth - this.sliderItemsToShow[0].offsetLeft) / this.sliderItemOffset
    );
    this.totalPages = this.sliderItemsToShow.length - this.slidesPerPage + 1;
    this.update();
  }

  resetPages() {
    this.sliderItems = this.querySelectorAll('[id^="Slide-"]');
    this.initPages();
  }

  update() {
    console.log('update');
    // Temporarily prevents unneeded updates resulting from variant changes
    // This should be refactored as part of https://github.com/Shopify/dawn/issues/2057
    if (!this.slider || !this.nextButton) return;

    const previousPage = this.currentPage;
    this.currentPage = Math.round(this.slider.scrollLeft / this.sliderItemOffset) + 1;

    if (this.currentPageElement && this.pageTotalElement) {
      this.currentPageElement.textContent = this.currentPage;
      this.pageTotalElement.textContent = this.totalPages;
    }

    if (this.currentPage != previousPage) {
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('slideChanged', {
          detail: {
            currentPage: this.currentPage,
            currentElement: this.sliderItemsToShow[this.currentPage - 1],
          },
        })
      );
    }

    if (this.enableSliderLooping) return;

    if (this.isSlideVisible(this.sliderItemsToShow[0]) && this.slider.scrollLeft === 0) {
      this.prevButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      this.prevButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }

    if (this.isSlideVisible(this.sliderItemsToShow[this.sliderItemsToShow.length - 1])) {
      this.nextButton.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      this.nextButton.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
  }

  isSlideVisible(element, offset = 0) {
    const lastVisibleSlide = this.slider.clientWidth + this.slider.scrollLeft - offset;
    return element.offsetLeft + element.clientWidth <= lastVisibleSlide && element.offsetLeft >= this.slider.scrollLeft;
  }

  onButtonClick(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const step = event.currentTarget.dataset.step || 1;
    this.slideScrollPosition =
      event.currentTarget.name === 'next'
        ? this.slider.scrollLeft + step * this.sliderItemOffset
        : this.slider.scrollLeft - step * this.sliderItemOffset;
    this.setSlidePosition(this.slideScrollPosition);
  }

  setSlidePosition(position) {
    this.slider.scrollTo({
      left: position,
    });
  }

  startDragging(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.startX = event.clientX;
    this.slider.classList.add('dragging');

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.onDrag);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDragging);

    console.log('Dragging started');
  }

  onDrag(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const dx = event.clientX - this.startX;
    this.slider.scrollLeft -= dx;
    this.startX = event.clientX;

    console.log('Dragging:', dx);
  }

  stopDragging(event) {
    this.slider.classList.remove('dragging');
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.onDrag);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.stopDragging);

    console.log('Dragging stopped');
  }
}
```

Comment: That component massively violates what a web component is allowed to do in its constructor. It's limited to declarative usage and making the components only known once the DOM is fully parsed. Please don't tell me the constructor part is from the Shopify team?

Comment: Yeah, this is from Shopify. This is my 1st time working with web components and was tasked with making this slider draggable :-/

They don't use the shadow DOM, I'm not sure if that's why its setup this way

You can see it here on their dawn theme
https://github.com/Shopify/dawn/blob/main/assets/global.js

Comment: Connexo is absolutely right. this ``constructor`` will fail when Web Components are defined **before** DOM is parsed, because there is no lightDOM yet. And when the element is created with ``document.createElement``, because there is no (light)DOM. Wouldn't be surprised if the Shopify team just whacks ``defer`` on their script loading, to _"solve"_ half the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, people might not be happy with the answer, but working with what Shopify has built this is the solution.

In the `constructor` I added

```
    this.isDragging = false;
    this.startX = 0;
    this.scrollStartX = 0;
    this.dragThreshold = 10;
    this.isLinkClickAllowed = true;

    this.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => this.startDrag(e));
    this.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => this.stopDrag(e));
    this.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => this.stopDrag(e));
    this.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => this.onDrag(e));
    this.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.onClick(e), true);
```

Then these methods to the comp:

```
/**
   * Handles the start of a drag event.
   * @param {MouseEvent} e
   */
  startDrag(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.isDragging = true;
    this.startX = e.pageX;
    this.scrollStartX = this.slider.scrollLeft;
    this.isLinkClickAllowed = true;
  }

  /**
   * Handles the drag event.
   * @param {MouseEvent} e
   */
  onDrag(e) {
    if (!this.isDragging) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentX = e.pageX;
    const dx = currentX - this.startX;

    // If we've dragged past a certain threshold, don't allow the click.
    if (Math.abs(dx) > this.dragThreshold) {
      this.isLinkClickAllowed = false;
    }

    this.slider.scrollLeft = this.scrollStartX - dx;
  }
  /**
   * Resets the isDragging state.
   * @param {MouseEvent} e
   */
  stopDrag(e) {
    this.isDragging = false;
  }
  /**
   * Prevents the click event from firing if the interaction was a drag.
   * @param {MouseEvent} e
   */
  onClick(e) {

    if (!this.isLinkClickAllowed) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      this.isLinkClickAllowed = true;
    }
  }
```